# css media query not working for Iphone (Chrome and Safari) / Apple MBP Safari

Tags: css, media-queries

I am starting a new site and was gathering some feedback for my to-develop CSS media query, to see which resolutions were reported by some devices

I asked some friends to test the css media query, and it turned out no Iphone user returned a result for the resolution part.

What it comes down to is when I use this code

```
@media only screen and (min-resolution: 5dpi)  {
    h1 {color: orange;}
    .desc1:after {content:" The resolution is for you";}
}
```

This works on all devices (desktops, android, chrome, firefox) except Iphones and Safari on the Mac (works on Chrome on the Mac)

In the head I have this line also:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Any guess why this does not work on some devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use "-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio" for Safari.  See http://www.w3.org/blog/CSS/2012/06/14/unprefix-webkit-device-pixel-ratio/